# Flutter, Firebase crashes app on email and password authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm using the regular use case for Firebase (It's a Flutter app) authentication. When I log in unsuccessfully, it gives me an error as expected. Whenever I successfully log in with it, it crashes my app with this message:

```
E/JavaBinder( 4289): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
E/JavaBinder( 4289): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcr.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
E/JavaBinder( 4289): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/JavaBinder( 4289):    ... 16 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289): FATAL EXCEPTION: Binder:4289_4
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289): Process: com.example.smartmoney, PID: 4289
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArrayMap;
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzc(Unknown Source:22)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzde(Unknown Source:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzam.zzdd(Unknown Source:8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzan.zzdf(Unknown Source:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzm.isAnonymous(Unknown Source:47)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzi(Unknown Source:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzat.zzg(Unknown Source:10)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$zzb.zza(Unknown Source:5)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcr.zzdx(Unknown Source:15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zzen(Unknown Source:35)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzen.zza(Unknown Source:41)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzep.zza(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdx.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(Unknown Source:13)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.util.ArrayMap" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.example.smartmoney-X1P2O9i7a7t81s9vttyrlA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4289):        ... 16 more
I/Process ( 4289): Sending signal. PID: 4289 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
```

Sorry about the error dump. I've been working on this error for many hours. Here is project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
           url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.0'  // Crashlytics plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.1'  // Performance Monitoring plugin

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's my app level gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.smartmoney"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1' // Firebase core
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1' // Firebase crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.1' // Firebase performance
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1' 


}
```

Here is my pubspec file:

```
name: smartmoney
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_bloc: ^0.14.0
  toast: ^0.1.5
  charts_flutter: ^0.6.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true



  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Any help is appreciated. I have no lead on this besides I guess there might be some sort of messes up Java library. Which makes little sense because I rebuilt my project and it still failed. So I'm more or less scratching my head on this.

Comment: Some have had success by doing the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42382457/3266152). Please try that and see whether this makes any difference for you :)

Comment: Tried it and it caused a gradle failure

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the gradle failure and now it looks like it's fixed.

Comment: @Alaric James Hartsock Hi, I have the same issue, how did you fix it? Would you mind sharing your gradle file?

Comment: @jgh yeah, [Project level gradle](https://gist.github.com/alarichartsock/dc01e339c3910fd8bdcbdd96e698e126), [App level gradle](https://gist.github.com/alarichartsock/c40ac1df030e9394f72ef77b356c061c)

Comment: [If you get an AndroidX failure, try this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

Please add the following lines in your gradle.properties file. It worked for me.

```
    android.useAndroidX = true
    android.enableJetifier = true
```

Thanks