# Firebase Authentication keeps crashing

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use Firebase phone authentication but it keeps crashing. It appears it has to do with Google Play Services.

Below are the crash logs.

````
packageName=com.geek.v
versionName=1.0
throwClassName=com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzah
throwMethodName=zzcy
throwLineNumber=25
exceptionMessage=There was an error while initializing the connection to Google Play Services: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArraySet;
exceptionClassName=java.lang.RuntimeException
stackTrace=
java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error while initializing the connection to Google Play Services: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/util/ArraySet;
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzah.zzcy(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzah.zzbq(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzah.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(Unknown Source)
    at com.geek.v.MainActivity.sendVerificationCode(MainActivity.java:75)
    at com.geek.v.MainActivity.access$1000006(MainActivity.java)
    at com.geek.v.MainActivity$100000000.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6190)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23226)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1073)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)```
````

This is my MainActivity where Firebase authentication is used.

```
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            // already signed in
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userNumber = phone_number.getText().toString();
                if(userNumber.isEmpty()) {}
                else {
                    sendVerificationCode(userNumber);
                    }
                    }      
                    });
    }

    private void sendVerificationCode(String mobile) {
       PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+234" + mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks);
            }

    private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            //Getting the code sent by SMS
            String code = phoneAuthCredential.getSmsCode();
            //sometime the code is not detected automatically
            //in this case the code will be null
            //so user has to manually enter the code
            if (code != null) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                phone_number.setText(code);
                //verifying the code
                verifyVerificationCode(code);
                }
                }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);
            //storing the verification id that is sent to the user
            mVerificationId = s;
            }
            };

    private void verifyVerificationCode(String code) {
        //creating the credential
         PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, code);
        //signing the user
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

    private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(MainActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //verification successful we will start the profile activity
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } 
                    else {
                        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //verification unsuccessful.. display an error message
                        String message = "Something went wrong";
                        if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            message = "Invalid code entered...";
                            }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        }
                        });
            }


}
```

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please add the code that produces this error.

Comment: I've updated it with the code

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382457/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-util-a (the first result when searching for the error essage)